# Locale issues with alternate locales

Tags: facebook-graph-api, locale

We are currently experience some troubles with our alternate locales.

When fetching the X-Facebook-Locale header/param from the request the param is missing the first time.

E.g. when I want to share an activity and use german in Facebook I get this:
[image: englisch post]

It starts german but the title and all other og tags are in en_us because we default to en_us when we get no param.

When I try the link in the debugger and click on the alternate locale links nothing changes an all the metatags stay english. 
[image: debugger englisch]

However when I curl the object with locale set to german:

`curl -X POST -F "id=http://www.runtastic.com/de/benutzer/max-runtastic-3/sportaktivitaeten/87052769" -F "scrape=true" -F "locale=de_de" "https://graph.facebook.com"`

The de_de params are not updated in the response:
"locale":{**"locale":"en_us"**,"alternate":["de_de","en_us","en_gb","es_es","it_it","fr_fr"]}

But the post gets updated properly:
[image: german posting]

When I check the url in the debugger it says:

> It appears that you are trying to change the property og:title from eine 13.53 km Inline-Skating-Aktivität in 0h 43m 35s to a 13.53 km skating activity in 0h 43m 35s. If so, you are not allowed to for this object because too many actions have been published against it.

and the action seems to be updated permanently to german.

When I check the server log, the first request of the crawler the locale empty, with the second request the locale de_de passed but it fetches the og tags after the first request which happen to be always english in our case because the header is empty.

Is anyone aware of any changes concerning the alternate locales? I found no changes and we used this solution for quite a while and it worked fine till now.